# UML with code generation tool for GNU/Linux

Tags: c++, linux, uml, gnu

Is there any tools for modeling software in UML which will be able to generate C++ code and keep the code implementation in the model?

ArgoUML, as far as I know, can just generate empty classes. If I want to add some code to an operation, I will have to do it later and it will not be kept in the model. I wish there was a tool like Artisan Studio for GNU/Linux. Maybe also a generator with reverse reading (If I make any changes to the code from my IDE, it will write it back to the model).

Answer (score 0):

[Modelio 2.2.1](http://modelio.org/downloads/download-modelio.html) have a C++ extension available [here](http://www.modeliosoft.com/fr/modelio-store/type/commercial.html). It keeps the code in the model (in stereotyped UML comment).

Comment: Is there a free extension for the generation? Is that easy to code a generator myself otherwise?

Comment: I do not know any free Modelio extension for C++ generation.. C++ generation and reversing for UML is more difficult than for Java. Concerning made your own C++ generation it will be easier without any reversing but it strongly depends of your C++ target. By the way all Modelio extension are Java code..

Comment: I think I'm gonna have to make one by myself. Hope it's easy.